# ABC class number from number module

Tags: python, python-2.7, abc, isinstance

ABC classes are created to check object type and as such they cannot be instantiated. In fact:

```
basestring()
```

throws:

```
TypeError: The basestring type cannot be instantiated
```

However, this does not happen for the ABC number:

```
from numbers import number

number()
```

it does not throw any exceptions. Whereas other ABCs from the same module do:

```
from numbers import Real
from numbers import Complex

Real()  # or Complex()
```

throws:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Real with abstract methods __abs__, __add__, __div__, __eq__, __float__, __floordiv__, __le__, __lt__, __mod__, __mul__, __neg__, __pos__, __pow__, __radd__, __rdiv__, __rfloordiv__, __rmod__, __rmul__, __rpow__, __rtruediv__, __truediv__, __trunc__
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

A look at the [source for the numbers module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/numbers.py) provides the answer:

> ```
> class Number(metaclass=ABCMeta):
>     """All numbers inherit from this class.
>     If you just want to check if an argument x is a number, without
>     caring what kind, use isinstance(x, Number).
>     """
>     __slots__ = ()
>
>     # Concrete numeric types must provide their own hash implementation
>     __hash__ = None
> ```

As you can see, the `numbers.Number` class has `abc.ABCMeta` as metaclass. And since it has no methods decorated with `@ab.cabstractmethod`, `@abc.abstractclassmethod` or `@abc.abstractstaticmethod` the `abc.ABCMeta` class does not prevent the instanciation.

The classes `numbers.Real` and `numbers.Complex` on the other hand inherit from `numbers.Number` and decorate many methods with `@abc.abstractmethod`, therefore they cannot be instanciated.

That means `numbers.Number` is most likely only instanciable because of the way abstract classes work in Python and not because someone specifically build it to be so.